# GWT RIA performance in IE8

Tags: performance, gwt, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9, gxt

We've got an application on GWT 2.5.0 + GXT 3.0.4 with one main page, containing a big table (like Excel) and a couple of heavy popups (implemented using GXT Windows). 
It works reasonably good at Chrome, FF, and IE9 but is incredibly slow in IE8.

Memory consumption on opening the main page and the most heavy popup is as follows:
FF  ~250Mb
IE9 ~230 Mb
IE8 ~600-700 Mb (!!) I don't think it's a memory leak, because memory stayed stable and didn't increase overnight.

Compiler settings are 'use closure compiler + max optimization'.

I'm at a loss where to start, and how to fix this problem. 
One idea was that rendering is fast in IE9 but not in IE8 because of a GPU acceleration, but that doesn't explain amount of memory needed for the IE8. Why then IE9 is okay, but not IE8 ?

We're currently profiling our application with dynatrace, but that doesn't help with memory usage. Any ideas greatly appreciated, thank you !

Comment: IE8 will be effectively dead in a year from now (WinXP, the only reason to continue using IE8, will be dead by then), so is it worth the effort? BTW, GWT will stop supporting IE8 before the end of next year (and IE6/7 before the end of this year)

Comment: Unfortunately as it often happens in the enterprise world our customer uses IE8 and refuses to drop it in the meanwhile

Comment: And that memory consumption really is a showstopper? I mean, what if IE8 is the culprit and nothing can be done (other than rearchitect the UI so that it puts less load on the browser)? (and IMO this is a serious hypothesis, which unfortunately could only be proved by recreating the same UI by other means). Maybe try cutting the CSS to make the least usage of images as possible (i.e. use a flat style, as IE8 supports neither rounded corners, nor shadows –nor gradients, but so does IE9); start by making sure you do not use `-ms-filter`. Just a few suggestions…

Comment: thank you, I'll try not using filters, and see if that helps or not